# How to convert int to double in a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line of code :

```
IEnumerable<double> katlar = ilanlarQuery.ToList()
                                         .Select(r => r.BulunduguKat.Value)
                                         .OrderBy(f => f);
```

I get error because `BulunduguKat.Value` is int, but `katlar` is double. How can I convert `BulunduguKat.Value` to double in this statement? Thanks.

Comment: ... by casting it?

Comment: Side-note: remove the `ToList`, it's inefficient to create a new List if you don't need it. If you need the result as list use `ToList` at the end. If `ilanlarQuery` is a database query and you want to use `Linq-To-Objects` use `AsEnumerable` instead.

Comment: @jason casting it is enough

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most straight forward way: just convert to `double`. By doing so you are telling that the `TResult` type of this `Select` operation is a `double` - making this an `IEnumerable<double>`

```
IEnumerable<double> katlar = ilanlarQuery.Select(r => (double)r.BulunduguKat.Value)
                                         .OrderBy(f => f);
```

Thanks to int being implicitly convertable to double this will work too:

```
IEnumerable<double> katlar  = ilanlarQuery.Select<YourType,double>(i => i.BulunduguKat.Value)
                                          .OrderBy(f => f)();
```

*Also, as you see you can remove the `.ToList()` before*

If indeed `BulunduguKat` is a `Nullable<int>` as Tim suggested then you should decide:

```
//If you don't want them in the result collection:
var katlar =  ilanlarQuery.Where(r => r.BulunduguKat.HasValue)
                          .Select(r => (double)r.BulunduguKat.Value)
                          .OrderBy(f => f)

//If you want them with some default value:
var katlar =  ilanlarQuery.Select(r => (double)(r.BulunduguKat.HasValue ? r.BulunduguKat.Value : 0))
                          .OrderBy(f => f);
```

Comment: First answer gives error, second answer doesn't have `BulunduguKat.Value`

Comment: @jason - corrected second. What is the erro of the first?

Comment: Btw, if the type is a `Nullable<int>` it could be `null`, then the cast will not succeed but give an `InvalidOperationException`. You should handle the case that `!r.BulunduguKat.HasValue`, for example with the conditional operator.

Comment: Added dealing with the case that it is a nullable type

Answer (score 0):

```
ds.Tables["#KAMPANYA"].AsEnumerable().Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s["KAMNO"])).ToList()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.